# CE marking of device that contains CE certified module

Tags: rf, radio, certification, ce

I am using a bluetooth module in an electronic product. This bluetooth module is CE certified.

When it comes to CE marking of the whole product, do I need to perform tests of the bluetooth part of the product?

Comment: Most probably yes.

Comment: There's no need to explain here as Dave from the EEVBlog made an excellent video about the CE marking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0uvS80YIGU&t=4s  In a nutshell: you as a manufacturer can simply "declare" that your product is CE compliant. No one says you need to test that. But if someone does test it and it fails you have a problem.

Comment: And if you CE mark it to declare it as safe and it hurts somebody then you have a REAL problem.

Comment: @Finbarr Or disturbs someone. Or if I happened to lay my hands on it and finds it to be questionable and report it to my local agency.

Comment: Also don't forget that there are institutions which function is to check this kind of products.

Answer (score 1):

What applies here is the Radio Equipment Directive (RED) 2014/53/EU. This in turn points at [a whole lot of technical standards](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/european-standards/harmonised-standards/red_en), as well as requirements from the Low Voltage Directive (LVD) regarding electrical safety. How much of it that applies in your case depends on the product. If I remember correctly, the relevant standard for Bluetooth devices is ETSI/EN 300 328. This standard should be available for free from ETSI.

If you don't change anything that will affect the radio characteristics of the product, then you shouldn't have to do any additional radio testing. Meaning for example that you *must* use one of the antennas that the manufacturer of the Bluetooth modules have used during their tests. This should also mean that you don't have to redo the tests for Bluetooth compliance - this isn't required by EU, but by the Bluetooth SIG.

However, you will have electronics surrounding the product, including a voltage regulator that provides supply voltage to the radio. These electronics need to conform to the EMC directive and you need to be sure that they don't affect the radio. That's the advantage of doing a formal radio test at a test house: you get EMC tests included, as EMC for devices containing radio is a special case where the RED directive overrides the EMC directive.

You need to write an EC declaration of conformity where your company vouches that the product fulfils the requirements of the RED directive. You can then chose different ways of ensuring that this is the case (set out in RED Article 17), including internal control or by using a test house ("notified body").